# Wheel event, and deltaY value for "mousewheel"

Tags: javascript

Looking at [MDN's polyfil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser) for the DOM3 `wheel` event, I found this line:

```
event.deltaY = - 1/40 * originalEvent.wheelDelta;
```

In the polyfil the `event` object for browsers not supporting dom3 event (wheel) is given a `deltaY`.
How is this proportion `1/40 * wheelDelta` calculated? Why `1/40`?

If I would create a similar polyfil for my library and would like to pass to event object the delta info, should I add both deltaX and deltaZ also? do the same proportions apply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why 1/40?**

Microsoft used the legacy and non-standard [`MouseWheelEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent).

That event has a `wheelDelta` property, which is ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel#wheelDelta.2C_wheelDeltaX_and_wheelDeltaY_value))

> an abstract value which indicates how far the wheel turned.

On IE, that value is usually ±120 ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel#IE))

> The value is the same as the delta value of `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` or
>   `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`. It means that if the mouse wheel doesn't support high
>   resolution scroll, the value is 120 per notch. The value isn't changed
>   even if the scroll amount of system settings is page scroll.

The polyfill uses a `deltaMode` of `1`. That means that ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent#Delta_modes))

> The delta values are specified in lines.

The default number of lines scrolled at a time is `3` (at least on Windows). You can change this number in Control Panel -> Mouse -> Wheel tab.

Then, `3 / 120` gives that `1 / 40` factor.

**Do the same proportions apply to other axis?**

Well, the problem is that ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel#wheelDelta.2C_wheelDeltaX_and_wheelDeltaY_value))

> IE and Opera (Presto) only support `wheelDelta` attribute and do not support horizontal scroll.

Therefore, the polyfill sets `deltaX` and `deltaZ` to `0`.